# node nested readline and writing causes MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, async-await, stream

I want to write a script that takes the line entries from the `source` file and searches this string in each line of the `search` file. If there's a match, I want the search line to be copied to the `output` file.

With my current script I only get one line written in the output file and a bunch of `MaxListenersExceededWarning` errors. But how can there be so many errors when I only have 3 streams?

Any help appreciated! :)

The errors:

```
(node:34238) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [Readable]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:34238) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 finish listeners added to [Readable]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:34238) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [Readable]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:34238) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [Readable]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:34238) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 readable listeners added to [Readable]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Here's my script:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

const sourceEngramFile = './super-structures-engrams.txt'
const searchEngramConfig = './all-engram-overrides.ini'
const outputEngramConfig = './output-super-structures.ini'

async function writeLine(stream, line) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    stream.write(line, 'utf8', resolve)
  })
}

async function processLineByLine() {
  const sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceEngramFile)
  const searchStream = fs.createReadStream(searchEngramConfig)
  const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputEngramConfig)

  const sourceRL = readline.createInterface({
    input: sourceStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  })

  const searchRL = readline.createInterface({
    input: searchStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  })

  // Possibly the error is caused by these nested loops/awaits
  for await (const sourceLine of sourceRL) {
    for await (const searchLine of searchRL) {
      if (searchLine.includes(`EngramEntry_${sourceLine}`)) {
        await writeLine(outputStream, searchLine)
      }
    }
  }
}

processLineByLine()
```

The source file looks like this:

```
Wall_Wood
Wall_Tek
Wall_Greenhouse
...
```

The search file looks like:

```
OverrideNamedEngramEntries=(EngramClassName="EngramEntry_Wall_Wood_C",EngramLevelRequirement=11,EngramPointsCost=7,EngramHidden=false,RemoveEngramPreReq=true)
OverrideNamedEngramEntries=(EngramClassName="EngramEntry_Hatchframe_Adobe_C",EngramLevelRequirement=16,EngramPointsCost=8,EngramHidden=false,RemoveEngramPreReq=true)
OverrideNamedEngramEntries=(EngramClassName="EngramEntry_Doorframe_Wood_C",EngramLevelRequirement=11,EngramPointsCost=6,EngramHidden=false,RemoveEngramPreReq=true)
...
```

Comment: For starters, I don't think you can use the `searchLine` stream over and over like you are without manually either starting a new stream or somehow resetting the stream to the beginning.  Remember, there's a regular readstream underneath that which has a file pointer as to how much you've read.

Comment: What do you mean by "use it over and over"? The for loop? I got that from the official ReadLine docs: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line
I just assumed I would be able to nest the for loops. If that's not possible, how would I go about this?

Comment: See my answer below for a description of the "use it over and over" problem.  You can only iterate a stream once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the maxListeners is caused by the trying to reuse the same `searchRL` object over and over for the inner `for` loop.  Each time you try to use it, it adds a new set of listeners to the underlying readStream and eventually you exceed the number of listeners where it issues a warning.  I was able to reproduce the same warning in a simple test app.

It's also the case that your inner `for` loop only works the first time though the outer loop anyway.  After that the `searchStream` is fully consumed and it never generates any more output.

Your loop here:

```
  // Possibly the error is caused by these nested loops/awaits
  for await (const sourceLine of sourceRL) {
    for await (const searchLine of searchRL) {
      if (searchLine.includes(`EngramEntry_${sourceLine}`)) {
        await writeLine(outputStream, searchLine)
      }
    }
  }
```

attempts to iterate the `searchRL` stream over and over again.  That does not work because the underlying readstream is entirely consumed upon the first iteration and from then on, the iterator has nothing to read.  This same issue also causes your eventListener problem.

If the searchStream can reasonably fit in memory, then you should probably read it into memory once so you can use it over and over again in the iteration of the sourceStream.  If not and you want to iterate it from the file each time, then you will probably have to create a new stream and a new readLine object each time through the outer loop so you have a fresh stream to iterate.

To demonstrate the problem I'm talking about, here's a little program that does nothing except try to iterate the same readLine object twice.  The first iteration gets the data we want.  The second gets no data because the underlying readstream has been completely consumed by the first iteration (e.g. the file pointer in the stream is pointing at the end of the file and thus has nothing else to read).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function run() {
    let rl = readline.createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream("file1.txt")});

    rl.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    console.log("start1");
    for await (const line of rl)  {
        console.log(line);
    }
    console.log("start2");
    for await (const line of rl)  {
        console.log(line);
    }
}

run().then(() => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Unfortunately, readStreams that point at a file don't have a built-in way to reset their state back to the start of the file so I think you'd have to just create a new stream and a new readLine object or read the stream into memory once and use it from memory rather than from the file every time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! The API feels a bit weird to me because `readline` suggests it only gets 1 line at a time, but I understand what's going now.
Creating a new stream for each line sounds slow, but since I want to understand streams better I guess it's the best way forward. Cheers.